# Detaching jQuery listeners from a deleted DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, listener

Does deleting a DOM element with the id `#foo` detach all jQuery listeners that reference that id? For example, if I have a listener on `$('#foo #bar')`, would that also automatically be deleted? (I am using the `elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)` method to delete the element.)

If I have to do manual cleanup, does using the jQuery `.off()` method like `$('#foo').off()` also detach all listeners which I attached using `$('#foo #bar').on('click', myFunction)`, or does that only detach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does deleting a DOM element with the id #foo detach all jquery listeners that reference that id?

It does if you use jQuery to do it, e.g.:

```
$("#foo").remove();
```

jQuery handles the cleanup for you. From [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/):

> In addition to the elements themselves, **all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed**.

*(my emphasis)*

And later, after an example removing `<div class="hello">`:

> If we had any number of nested elements inside `<div class="hello">`, they would be removed, too. **Other jQuery constructs such as data or event handlers are erased as well.**

*(my emphasis)*